# month as an adjective

Tags: attributive-nouns, attributive-adjectives

For the sentence, "I am going on a two month cruise", would "two month" be considered an adjective since it means two months long. Also, is the correct wording "two months" or is "two month" also correct. I have heard it used both ways (months/month).

Comment: "Two-month" is best classified as a compound adjective with the singular noun "month" as the second component.

Comment: @user405662 No, it's not a determiner but a compound adjective. Note that determiners are not normally modifiers; I recall pointing that out to you once before.

Comment: Note: a compound adjective of size, length, etc, needs a hyphen: a six-metre pole, a five-hour journey, a ten-kilo sack, a two-month cruise.

Comment: Indeed! Sorry, it had slipped my mind. I will remove it. Thank you, @BillJ.

Comment: It's a classical example of adjectivizing a noun.

Comment: @BillJ - you showed a hyphen in your comment, but did not make it clear that it was needed. –

Comment: Yes, since it's a compound, it requires a hyphen, otherwise it would be two separate words in a syntactic construction.

Comment: So, two-month cruise vs two-months cruise. Are both correct? is one more "proper"?

Comment: @DougfromAtlanta  Hyphenated compound adjectives of measure use the singular form of the noun of measure, so a ten-pound weight, a two-foot pole, a six-month jail sentence, a hundred-year-old egg, and a two-month cruise. A two-months cruise is incorrect.